# Capitalized Word Function

Tags: python

I Am writing a function that should take a string input and return the string with every first letter of every word as a capital letter, I have achieved this to a certain degree.

My Code:

```
string = input("Please Enter A string:")

def capitalize_words(string):
    split = string.split()

    letter1 = ''
    letter2 = ''
    letter3 = ''

    str1 = split[0]
    str2 = split[1]
    str3 = split[2]

    for i in str1:
        if i in str1[0]:
            first = i.upper()
        else:
            letter1 = letter1 + i
            string1 = (first+letter1)

    for i in str2:
        if i in str2[0]:
            first = i.upper()
        else:
            letter2 = letter2 + i
            string2 = (first+letter2)

    for i in str3:
        if i in str3[0]:
            first = i.upper()
        else:
            letter3 = letter3 + i
            string3 = (first+letter3)

    result = string1+' '+string2+' '+string3
    return result


func = capitalize_words(string)
print(func)
```

Input:

```
Please Enter A string:herp derp sherp
```

Output:

```
Herp Derp Sherp
```

However this is very inflexible because i can only enter 3 words with spaces no more no less , this makes for a rather primal program. I would like to be able to enter anything and get the desired result of the first letter of every word being a capital letter no matter how many words i enter.

I fear with my skills this is as far as I am able to get, can you please improve my program if possible.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods lists more useful string methods, such as `.title` needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.title()` to achieve what you want in one go.

But to process words in a sentence, use a loop instead of a series of local variables; here is a version that does the same what you are doing for an arbitrary number of words:

```
for i, word in enumerate(split):
    split[i] = word[0].upper() + word[1:]

result = ' '.join(split)
```

I used string slicing as well to select just the first character, and all but the first character of a word. Note the use of `enumerate()` to give us a counter which wich we can replace words in the `split` list directly.

Comment: This may not work with something like : `"herp derp ,sherp"`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Sure, but that is a limitation of `.split()` more than anything. I'm addressing the "can only process 3 elements" side of the question here.

Comment: Great Thanks I will always remember the .title function now, however improved mechanics of how to build the function is more what i was interested in so thumbs up for you :)

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> print(raw_input('Please Enter A string: ').title())
Please Enter A string: herp derp sherp
Herp Derp Sherp
```

Comment: Ahh so there is a built in function for this

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to use `re.sub` such as:

```
re.sub(r'\b.', lambda c: c.group().upper(), 'herp derp sherp and co.')
# 'Herp Derp Sherp And Co.'
```

Comment: As usual with questions involving natural language parsing, the answers can only handle a small subset of valid cases. At least, your code handles `"quotes"` and `(braces)` correctly, but fails on words with dashes, like `so-called`. Still, +1 for the correct approach, regexes are the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this in a one-line generator expression:

```
def upper_case(text):
    return ' '.join(w[0].upper() + w[1:] for w in text.split())
```

Notice, that this function fails on single letter words and replaces any whitespace by a single space character.

Use this as

```
In [1]: upper_case(input('Please Enter A string: '))
Please Enter A string: hello world
Out[1]: 'Hello World'
```